# Wordpress pagination always returns same 3 posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

So I have created dedicated page template, and on this page I want to list the 3 most recent blog posts, with the usual pagination links to take users to the previous or next 3 posts.

I have the list populated, and the links are appearing, but when I click on either the previous or next links I just get the same 3 posts as before. I can see the URL changes (/blog/page/2) but the posts being shown are always the three most recent ones.

UPDATE. After getting very frustrated I decided to take things back to basics. The following snippet is the only code I had in my template, just to isolate the loop basically, and this STILL didn't fix it. All I get is a singple post on the page, BUT if I manually type /page/2 at the end of the url it takes me to page 2 with a different post showing. However, the only link I see to do with pagination is 'Newer Posts' (and that only appears on page 2). How come 'older' posts isn't showing up?

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'paged'         => $paged,
);

$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
?>

<article>
    <h2 class="fnt25 noBtmMarg"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Read: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="meta fnt18 pMarginBottom">Posted on: <?php the_date(); ?></div>

    <div class="fnt22"><?php print_custom_field('listingDesc'); ?></div>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="floatRight fnt22" title="Read the full article: <?php the_title(); ?>">Read more...</a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</article>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```

Comment: Are you accessing or manipulating wp_query (or get_posts/get_post or the $post object) before this block of code? Also, by any chance are some of the posts you are accessing custom-posts?

Comment: No this block of code is the first time I'm going near the wp_query or the loop. I do have custom post types, but I do not want them to be included, which is why I am being specific about the 'post' item type.

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming you have more than just 3 total posts (that aren't custom-posts). Under that assumption maybe this suggestion from wordpress? "This function will not work (fail silently) if mysql.trace_mode is enabled in your php.ini. If you can't edit that file, try adding ini_set( 'mysql.trace_mode', 0 ); to your theme's functions.php". Alternatively, what happens when you don't suggest a specific post_type, does it work then (showing both posts and custom-posts)?

Comment: Indeed I do, I have 6 posts in total so page 2 should fill up. I tried editing the functions.php file with the code, but that made no difference to the outcome. Changing the code to remove the post type stopped it working altogether. The page still rendered but didn't return any posts... Would it be useful to see the full page code up to the point where I copied the bit I already pasted?

Comment: I have updated the original snippet to include the whole page up to my query... Any better?

Comment: first thing that pops out is that you shouldn't be using `include()` to get your header for wordpress. You should be using `<?php get_header(); ?>`. Also, there may be some configuration in your header that may be causing the conflict. Would you be able to post your header as well?

Comment: I'm doing it that way so that I can pass a variable back to be used as a class in the rendered code. It didn't work otherwise. I have added the head code now too.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's wrong but it may have to do with using `include()` instead of `get_header()`. Why not try using `get_header` (if you haven't already) to see if it works then (perhaps it has some internal persistence that works as a result of it being a function and not just including a file) if it does work, than at least you've isolated the issue. Let me know! I apologize that I can't give you such a clean answer.

Comment: For reference to your other problem (persisting variables) you can gain access to them by doing this `<?php global $missing_var; ?>` I believe. Add that to gain access/modify said variable and persist.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the variable that worked. However, switching back to get_header() did not solve the pagination issue...

Is there another way you would setup the pagination? I know there are tons of ways to call in a list of posts and I am by no means married to the method I am using at the moment.

Comment: I've found http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-pagination-a-primer/ to be really helpful. There is an explanation for an alternative options at the bottom called "A Better Solution". Look into that. The only other thing I could imagine being a problem is in your footer. But go through that tutorial, perhaps it mite clarify some things that we aren't seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that link. Just as a quick and dirty test I tried not calling the footer, but it had no effect on the pagination. I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: I've just updated the original question with my latest effort, stripping everything out EXCEPT for the loop basically, and that still didn't fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Okay. After doing a little bit of research myself, it seems that the `query_posts()` is not the best for this type of scenario. Use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), read up on it a bit as well.

A good example (EDIT: better description):

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'paged'         => $paged,
);

$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Comment: That returns only 1 post and doesn't display any pagination links. Don't you need to specify that pagination is turned on?

I've double checked and I have 5 published blog posts, so am fairly certain it's not a content issue.

Comment: No, in fact all it seems to be doing is listing one link that is self referencing. Whether that's because it's linking to something that's not there (effectively just #) or if there's something odd in the query making it link to the current template rather than posts....

Comment: sorry about that, multiple things at once. I reformatted the code in a way that makes more sense and is much more concise (and you're rite, i totally forgot the `paged` attribute.

Comment: I think we are nearly there!! I put it in and it seems to work (if I got to url/page/2 I get the remaining posts. But where do I call in the pagination links? I've tried doing it after the endforeach but that doesn't work...

Comment: try this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/installation/. and place `<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>` after the `foreach`. Hopefully that works!

Comment: I think this may end my web design days! I have updated my original post with the current code I am using and described the problem now. On the standard page I get no pagination links, but on page 2 I see 'newer posts' only. Clicking it takes me back to page 1 which then gets rid of any pagination links. Using that plugin removed the links altogether...

Thanks for your patience with this and for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; // setup pagination

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 1) 
    );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<div>' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
              the_content();
    endwhile;


    echo '<nav>';
    echo  '<div class="nav-previous alignleft">'.get_next_posts_link('Older posts', $the_query->max_num_pages).'</div>'; //Older Link using max_num_pages
    echo  '<div class="nav-next alignright">'.get_previous_posts_link('Newer posts', $the_query->max_num_pages).'</div>'; //Newer Link using max_num_pages
    echo "</nav>";


    wp_reset_postdata(); // Rest Data
```

Would you please check above code?